# Mobile Backend Starter does not work "out-of-the-box"

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to test the Google App Engine - [Mobile Backend Starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/) which I have deployed the backend and the admin is accessible.

The problem is in the Android client which throws this error when trying to send a message from the client:

```
10-22 03:14:01.990: W/AbstractGoogleClient(675): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
10-22 03:14:06.840: D/dalvikvm(675): GC_CONCURRENT freed 462K, 14% free 5685K/6535K, paused 15ms+23ms, total 92ms
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675): error: 
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675): Not Found
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackend.insert(CloudBackend.java:111)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync.access$0(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:87)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
10-22 03:14:06.870: I/CloudBackend(675):    at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:428)
```

I don't understand what is `Not Found` here? I mean I am sure I have typed the PROJEC_ID properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/CloudBackend(675): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found

A `404 not found` means it's doing a HTTP request to an address that is wrong / doesn't have a website.

So I'm guessing that you're supplying the wrong URL somewhere during your setup?

Comment: Yes, but I have typed the PROJECT_ID properly, and thus it should point to the working online backend